# update view don't save the bank

Tags: python, django, postgresql

**I wanted to know how I do it here to update this form in the bank, I am using 2 forms with different models and every time I try to save the information they are not exchanged and I get an invalid form error.**

```
class PacienteUpdateView(UpdateView):

    queryset = Endereco_pacientes.objects.all().select_related('cpf')
    form_class = PacientesModelForm
    second_form_class = EnderecoPacientesModelForm
    template_name = 'pacientes/pacientesForm.html'
    #get_success_url = '.'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PacienteUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form_class(instance=self.object.cpf)
        context['form2'] = self.second_form_class(instance=self.object)
        print(context['form'])
        return context
```

**I can already display the information in HTML, but I cannot update
I thank the attention**